# Gumbel distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. normal $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables. Let $M_n = \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i$. Show that 
$$P[\sqrt{2 \log n} M_n - 2 \log n \leq u ] \rightarrow e^{-e^{-u}} \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$
I thought maybe to use the following property:
$$P[\sqrt{2 \log n} M_n - 2 \log n \leq u ] = P(M_n \leq \frac{u+2 \log n}{\sqrt{2 \log n}})= F^n(\frac{u+2 \log n}{\sqrt{2 \log n}})$$ but dont know how to proceed..

Comment: are you sure? I don't get the same result.

Comment: I thought maybe using the following property:
$P[\sqrt{2 \log n} M_n - 2 \log n \leq u] = P[M_n \leq \frac{u+2 \log n}{\sqrt{2 \log n}}] = F^n ( \frac{u+2 \log n}{\sqrt{2 \log n}})$ but then i dont know how to proceed..

Comment: This comment is your most interesting contribution: it should be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentionned,$$P[a_n M_n - b_n \leq u ] =
F\left(\frac{u +b_n}{a_n}\right)^n
$$
[As](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function)
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}(x+1/x)}\exp\left(-\frac {x^2}2\right) < 1-F(x) <
\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}x}\exp\left(-\frac {x^2}2\right),\\
1-F(x) \sim \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}x}\exp\left(-\frac {x^2}2\right).
$$

$$
-\log P[a_n M_n - b_n \leq u ] = -n\log \left(1-\left( 1-
F\left(\frac{u +b_n}{a_n}\right)\right)\right)\\
\sim n \left( 1-
F\left(\frac{u +b_n}{a_n}\right)\right)
\sim n \frac {a_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}(u+b_n)}
\exp\left(-\frac {(u+b_n)^2}{2a_n^2}\right)
\sim  n \frac {a_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}b_n}
\exp\left(-\frac {(u+b_n)^2}{2a_n^2}\right);
\\
\exp\left(-\frac {(u+b_n)^2}{2a_n^2}\right)=
\exp\left(-\frac {u^2}{2a_n^2}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac {ub_n}{a_n^2}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac {b_n^2}{2a_n^2}\right)
\sim \frac {\exp\left(-u\right)}n
$$
because $a_n\to\infty$,
$a_n^2 = b_n$ and $(b_n/a_n)^2 = 2\log n$.

Comment: Are u sure? Because if I want to compute this limit with Mathematica as $n \rightarrow \infty$ with the given values for $a_n$ and $b_n$, I get $\infty$ as result or did i make a typo...?

Comment: I checked it again, the inital question is correct, at least it's stated like this in the exercise..

Comment: The double inequality is valid for $1-F$, not for $F$. If you correct this and follow the idea in your answer, the result should come...

Comment: Well... what comes next?

Comment: Where did the second line with the two inequalities come from?

Comment: this is the study of the integrand: decreasing and convex.

Comment: Do you plan to complete the proof?

Comment: can someone give me a hint how to complete the proof?

Comment: this is where is stopped. There seem to be a problem at the end with the ratio $(a_n/b_n)$.\

Comment: Can u explain why the following holds:  $$-n\log \left(1-\left( 1- F\left(\frac{u +b_n}{a_n}\right)\right)\right) \sim n \left( 1- F\left(\frac{u +b_n}{a_n}\right)\right)$$

Comment: this is $\log (1-u) \sim -u$ when $u\to 0$

Comment: We got the hint, that for large $t$ the following holds: $$P(X_i>t) \sim \frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \sim e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$ and with this and your argumentation, I think I can finish the proof

Comment: the $\sim$, meaning that the limit of the ratio goes to 1, is inappropriate.

Comment: in my opinion, there is still the raito $a_n/b_n$ making the limits out of control...

Comment: Indeed, the exercise was wrong and we got the corrected exercise with new $a_n$ and $b_n$. Why does the last "$\sim$" hold in your calculation?

Comment: as $a_n\to\infty$ the first term goes to 1. the second one simplifies to $\exp(-u)$ and the fird term equals $1/n$

Comment: sorry I meant this one: $$n \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}(u+b_n)}...\sim n \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}(b_n)}...$$

Comment: because $u$ is fixed and $a_n\to\infty$